# Paramiko return code on successful login

Tags: python, ssh, return-value, paramiko

I am using paramiko to login to a set of servers and just check if my credentials work.I do not need to run any further commands.I know the exceptions raised for authentication failure and connection error.However,I am not sure of what is returned on a successful login..This is what I have so far :

```
f1 = open('hostfile','r')
devices = f1.readlines()

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


for device in devices:
    try:
            ssh.connect(device, username=username, password=password, timeout=4)
            <IF CONDITION MET THEN>
            output= "Successfully Authenticated"
            ssh.close()
    except  paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            output = "Authentication Failed"
            print output
    except  socket.error, e:
            output = "Connection Error"
            print output
```

What do I substitute the "IF CONDITION MET THEN" with ?

Comment: i assure you that I am not even remotely trying to do anything like that..I have close to 600 odd servers on which an audit needs to be run for user access and hence this script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need a IF CONDITION. Because if authentication fails, script will anyway raise exception and will not execute rest of the statements

So you should just put the statements after `ssh.connect`, as they will only be executed if the connection is successful.

If you still want to put IF CONDITION what you can do is

```
conn = ssh.connect(device, username=username, password=password, timeout=4)

if conn is None:
         print "Successfully Authenticated"
```

Comment: DA14..I do not want to execute anything after successful execution..i just need to check if i am authenticated,print it,close the connection and move to the next device in the for loop..I will give the if conditioned that you mentioned a shot and get back to you in some time..